# Request Timed out - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I run a query that gives me 8000 records.It is giving me error in mean time:

> Network Access Message: The page cannot be displayed
>
> Explanation: The request timed out before the page could be retrieved.
>
> Try the following:
> Refresh page: Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The
> timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion.
> Check spelling: Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. The
> address may have been mistyped.
> Contact website: You may want to contact the website administrator to make
> sure the Web page still exists. You can do this by using the e-mail address
> or phone number listed on the website home page.
> If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your
> administrator or Helpdesk.

There is no error in the query.

Comment: ??? where is your code? who throws the message?

Comment: how much time your query is taking if executing directly on db.

Comment: It is taking 2-3 mintues on db

Comment: Actually the query is too big..i can't print here

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this might be a problem with your server configuration. The server is cutting off the request after a certain amount of time. Check out the `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini`.

The real root of the issue is the long running query. Make sure your indexes are optimised and consider denormalising a view of the data for quick access.

Comment: in my php.ini max_execution_time - 600 and query is also optimized.Still getting the error.

Comment: Are there any errors in your PHP or Apache error logs?